# Java useDelimiter and file reading

Tags: java

I have problem regard to delimiter

Inside the main I have

```
    Scanner in= new Scanner(new File("num.txt"));
        in.useDelimiter("\\D"); 
        while(in.hasNext()){
    System.out.print(in.next());
    }
```

Where num.txt has

```
2,3,4
6,3,2
1,2,3
```

The output is 234632123, but when I change "in.next()" to "in.nextInt()" I get

```
234Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at examTest.Testing.main(Testing.java:23)
```

If in.next() output 234632123, then how come in.nextInt() doesn't work?

EDIT

If i use

```
in.useDelimiter("\\D+")
```

instead of

```
in.useDelimiter("\\D")
```

then nextInt() will scan the digit properly

```
    Scanner in= new Scanner(new File("num.txt"));
       in.useDelimiter("\\D+"); 
       while(in.hasNext()){
    System.out.print(in.nextInt());
    }
```

But I still don't know why the first version doesn't work

Comment: Even in.next() is also working for me.Which version java you are working.

Comment: in.next() work for me. The real problem is why in.nextInt() doesn't work, especially when in.next() output pure integer

Comment: Try in.hasNextLine() mentioned in below answer.

Comment: Does that work for you? because it is giving me  java.util.InputMismatchException.

Comment: Yes its working fine.Change the data in that file and create a new file , then test again.

Comment: No it still doesn't work. However, if I use println() instead of print() then I will get "234 632 123". I think it is the white space character that is causing problem, but I don't get why it doesn't appear in print()

Comment: May be you are right.But, its working for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change it to check whether you have a `int` in the next token and then call `Scanner.nextInt()`. You can do that by

```
if(in.hasNextInt())
in.nextInt();
```

Comment: I tried that before. It only print the very first line (234)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this , its working for me.

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner in= new Scanner(new File("Experiment/src/test/java/example/num.txt"));
        in.useDelimiter("\\D"); 
         while(in.hasNextLine()){
            System.out.print(in.nextInt());
        }
    }
```

Output :-
234632123

Try `in.hasNextLine()` instead of `in.hasNext()`.Read [Scanner.html#nextInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29)

Hope it will help you.

Comment: the OP has posted the same code right? What was the fix here? I'd like to understand.